# How vba click for class and title only button

Tags: vba, getelementsbyclassname

I found the site with a sidebar, but i can't find a right code to click on it.

```html
<div class="sidebar">
<div id="menuTree">
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="No1"><a class="here" title="My Merchants" action="../app/rps/merchant/filter_merchant.jsp" tree_id="rps0301">My Merchants</a></li>
    <li class="No2"><a class="" title="My Terminals" action="../app/rps/terminal/filter_terminal.jsp" tree_id="rps0401">My Terminals</a></li>
    <li class="No3"><a class="" title="My Templates" action="../app/rps/template/filter_template.jsp" tree_id="rps1101">My Templates</a></li>
    <li class="No4"><a class="" title="My Reports">My Reports</a><ul class="No_1" style="display: none;">
    <li><a title="Parameter Report" action="../app/rps/myreport/parameter_filter.jsp" tree_id="rps5002">Parameter Report</a></li>
    <li><a title="Health Monitor" action="../app/rps/health/healthmonitoring/filter_health.jsp" tree_id="rps3008">Health Monitor</a></li>
    <li><a title="User Report" action="../app/rps/log_management/log_mng.jsp...
```

i use the class name but still not able to click it.

```
Dim e
Set e = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("here")(1)
e.Click
```

please advise.

Comment: What error are you getting? "Subscript out of range"? Have you tried verifying how many items are returned by `getElementsByClassName`? That `1` is skipping index `0`, which looks like what you're after.

Comment: There is no button tag element. What are you trying to click on? You have links for My Merchants
My Terminals
My Templates
My Reports Parameter Report and Health Monitor

Comment: Did you get the answer below to work please?

Comment: can not locate that object

Comment: The code is updated please check when you have a moment.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no parent frame/iframe you can use an attribute=value CSS selector. This first is more specific.

```
ie.document.querySelector("[title='My Merchants']").Click
```

Or a class selector of

```
ie.document.querySelector(".here").Click
```

That relies on you wanting the first element with class `here`.

Comment: Much cleaner. I'll just stick to desktop stuff :D

Comment: That is kind. Appreciated.

Comment: while i used ie.document.querySelector("title='My Merchants'").Click,      
      it gave error ," Method ' querySelector' of object'JScriptTypeInfo'Failed"   and when i use ie.document.querySelector(".here").Click                                                       it gave error, " Object required"...

Comment: Oh..cos the first is missing outers for some reason. Use this ie.document.querySelector("[title='My Merchants']").Click  as per edit.

Comment: i had realized it, i putted it back, before i run the test, still the same...no luck...any other suggestion?

Comment: What happens now when you run it?